# Why does this while loop in java run?

Tags: java, networking, while-loop

**UPDATE:** I am an idiot. The server has a line `out.println((String) null);` which the client used to know when to stop and disconnect. Turns out that line was unnecessary and *probably* where the "null" was coming from (I don't know how tat got turned into a string, but...) But thank you all for your help!

I'm writing a client-server program, in which the client terminates as soon as the server sends it null. The loop in question is:

```
while ((message = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("C: Recieved " + message + " from server");
}
```

The output is:

```
C: Recieved Hi from server
C: Recieved null from server
```

The server sends a `null` to the client after sending the hi and before calling `close()` on the client. I probably should have mentioned this earlier, but I'm using the classes Socket and ServerSocket in java.net. But why is the while loop running twice, entering even when message is `null`?

Edit: The line where the server sends a null is `out.println((String) null);`. Does that get converted to the String "null"?

Comment: I suspect the server is sending `"null"` (a String), which is not `null` (the null reference).

Comment: `"" + null` produces `"null"`, while `(String) null` is still `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The *string* `"null"` is not the same as the value `null`. The value `null` is returned by `readline()` where there is no more data.

As per the Java docs, `readline` returns a:

> String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.

If your server is sending the string `"null"`, that's actually non-null data.